# Float and int comparision

Tags: c, floating-point, int

In below program, i didnt understand how float and int value are same.

```
int main()
{
    int a=3;
    float b=3.0;
    if(a==b)
    {
        printf("A is equal to b");
    }
    else{
        printf("A is not euql to b");
    }
}
```

The output of the program is "A is equal to b"

Comment: There are no heterogeneous comparisons. In the expression `a == b`, the operands are first *converted* to a common type.

Comment: What is the problem? The `int` is converted to `float` and compared to `b`. For the value 3, it happens that the converted value matches 3.0.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161199/is-relational-comparison-between-int-and-float-directly-possible-in-c

Answer (score 3):

`if(a==b)` does not compare types, it compares values.

---

As [@Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463159/float-and-int-comparision#comment52788404_32463159) commented, the value(s) are converted to a common type.

Each `a` and `b` go though "usual arithmetic conversions" before the comparison.

> ... the **values** yielded by operators with floating operands and values **subject to the usual arithmetic conversions** and of floating constants are evaluated to a format whose **range and precision may be greater** than required by the type.  The use of evaluation formats is characterized by the implementation-defined value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`:  C11dr §5.2.4.2.2 9

Conversion to floating point is to `float`, `double` or `long double` depending on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

Assuming conversion to `float`...:

> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>   corresponding real type is `float`. §6.3.1.8 1

So `a` converts to a `float` with the *value* of `3.0` before the comparison.

Since the values compare the same, they pass the `if(a==b)`.

---

Note: Conversion can cause issues as not all `int` may covert exactly to a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the int value will be typecasted to float and then the if condition is evaluated.