# Conditional rule constant

Tags: c, boolean, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I have written a conditional constant where I want to tell the the machine what it already knows to define a rule. however, all outputs are set to 0.0000 floating. That's not the issue, the issue is, I was expecting a 1 or -1 in certain conditions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

float zero = 0.0;
float pos = 1.0;
float neg = -1.0;
float RULE;
float x, y, z;

//#define RULE (neg < zero < pos);

float main() {

    #define RULE (neg < zero < pos);

    float a, b, c, d, e;
    
    a = RULE(pos > zero) ? pos : zero;
    b = RULE(zero > pos) ? zero : pos;
    c = RULE(neg > pos) ? neg : pos;
    d = RULE(neg > zero) ? neg : zero;
    e = RULE(pos > neg) ? pos : neg;
    
    printf("(pos > zero) pos ?: zero %f \n", a);
    printf("(zero > pos) zero ?: pos %f \n", b);
    printf("(neg > pos) neg ?: pos %f \n", c);
    printf("(neg > zero) neg ?: zero %f \n", d);
    printf("(pos > neg) pos ?: neg %f \n", e);
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I am new to C.

Terminal Output:

(pos > zero) pos ?: zero 0.000000 
(zero > pos) zero ?: pos 0.000000 
(neg > pos) neg ?: pos 0.000000 
(neg > zero) neg ?: zero 0.000000 
(pos > neg) pos ?: neg 0.000000

Comment: [Can we have an official statement regarding greetings, salutations etc. please?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351588/can-we-have-an-official-statement-regarding-greetings-salutations-etc-please)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things completely wrong with this. I highly suggest picking up a good C book before proceeding. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for good C books.

Now, to explain what's wrong. I honestly have no idea what you are trying to do so I'll just explain what you're doing wrong, and the reasons behind the behavior you're seeing.

Firstly, `float main()` is not a valid signature for the main function. According the C standard, the `main` function **must return integers**.

> 5.1.2.2.1
>
> Program startup
>
> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
> ```c
>  int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they
> are local to the function in which they are declared):

> ```c
>  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

So definitely change that to `int main(void)` first. (`int main()` also works but they are not actually the same)

Now, this macro-

```c
#define RULE (neg < zero < pos);
```

So, this is how this `#define` macro works- wherever it sees `RULE` in your code, (i.e `RULE(pos > zero) ? pos : zero;`) it replaces it with `(neg < zero < pos);`

So, when you write-

```c
a = RULE(pos > zero) ? pos : zero;
```

It becomes,

```c
a = (neg < zero < pos);(pos > zero) ? pos : zero;
```

Which is the same as-

```c
a = (neg < zero < pos);
(pos > zero) ? pos : zero;
```

Yeah.....that makes no sense....at all. Every single variable is just storing the result of `(neg < zero < pos)` and the ternary (`(pos > zero) ? pos : zero;`) is being completely ignored, because the result is not stored anywhere.

**Please** study carefully how `#define` works, it's not difficult - trust me :). Here's is a pretty good guide at [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace)

But wait! there's more- `(neg < zero < pos)` <- this doesn't do what you probably think it does.
This just gets grouped to-

```c
(neg < zero) < pos
```

So this first evaluates-

```c
neg < zero
```

Which is obviously `1` (aka true), because indeed, -1.0 is less than 0.0
Then it compares this result to `pos`-

```c
1 < pos
```

`pos` is 1.0; Comparing floats to ints is a bad idea, both `1 < 1.0` and `1 > 1.0` *may* evaluate to 0 (i.e false) which is what your machine is doing. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161199/is-relational-comparison-between-int-and-float-directly-possible-in-c)

So those are the reasons why it's always 0. Your ternaries are completely ignored every single variable gets the result of the same calculation, that is `(neg < zero < pos)`

Once again, I suggest following a good C book. Whoever taught you to write `float main` certainly is not a good teacher, not when it comes to C.